# Setting up a TreeView in Silverlight with a HierarchicalDataTemplate and Binding with ItemSource

Tags: silverlight, binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate, itemsource

I am trying to build a TreeView and have it set up like this link:

[Silverlight vs WPF - Treeview with HierarchialDataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319358/silverlight-vs-wpf-treeview-with-hierarchialdatatemplate)

As a comment to the first actual answer provided the poster says how they solved it but they didn't provide code and I understand what they said but I am really new to this and can't get it right.  I have the same set-up structure with the entities and groups.  I was wondering if some one could explain what the xaml ended up looking like.  I am assuming by saying they made a new node class it just means they made a class that contains essentially a list of groups.  Something like

```
class groupHolder
{
   public List<Group> myGroups {get;set;}
   public groupHolder() { myGroups = new List<Group>(); } 
}
```

I am just trying to go three levels deep:

Group 1 
- - - - AnotherGroup1 
- - - - - - - - entity1 
- - - - - - - - entity2 
- - - - AnotherGroup2
- - - - - - - - entity1
Group2
- - - - Entity1
- - - - Entity2
- - - - AnotherGroup1
- - - - - - - - entity1
- - - - - - - - entity2
- - - - AnotherGroup2
- - - - - - - - entity1
and so on...

Like I said, I am new to this.  I've also been trying to use this tutorial:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/davids/archive/2009/06/04/hierarchicaldatatemplate-and-treeview.aspx

but when I try and set another HierarchicalDataTemplate it says that ItemTemplate is set more than once.  I'm lost.

---

edit:  found this link on the web, it helps, too.... I think...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36451/Organizing-Heterogeneous-Data-on-a-WPF-TreeView.aspx

Comment: In your case is Group1 the same type as AnotherGroup1?

Comment: Oh, i typed that wrong... the class myGroups.  It's supposed to be List<Group> myGroups... then = new List<Group>();

Comment: Yes... like the first link, I have a group like class and an like entity.  The group class can contain other groups and entities.  The example from the first link shows Groups on the same level as Entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to re-create that structure:

TreeView:

```
 <sdk:TreeView Grid.Row="2"                                            
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Groups}">            
        </sdk:TreeView>
```

Templates:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>       
        <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="EntryTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SubGroupTemplate"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Entries}"
                                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EntryTemplate}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SubGroups}"
                                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SubGroupTemplate}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

In the ViewModel I have:

```
public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
```

Rest:

```
 public class Group
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Group> SubGroups { get; set; }
        public List<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    }

  public class Entry
    {
        public int Key { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Ooo, thank you.  Let me play with it for a minute and I'll get back to you.  Thank you so much, I have no idea why this was so had for me to understand.

Comment: I had to do something similar and it took me a bit also.  Once I figured out how setting the templates ItemSource worked, it made sense.